# Asker upvote prevail among equal votes number?

Tags: feature-request, up-votes, question-order

Idea for improve answers ordering: asker upvote should count as 1.5 upvotes, so his upvoted answers (probably more valuable than others) will come before others with the same votes count.

Comment: That big tick already counts as 1.5 normal votes.

Answer (score 7):

The person asking is not often the person who knows what's best and that's where the community comes in with their votes. Also they wouldn't be asking if they knew the question, unless they were out to ask and answer it themselves.

Another thing is this would be a good way to prime up some sock-puppet accounts if the asker has their fingers poking in some sub-par answers and votes them up just because their votes would weigh more.

Answer (score 4):

The person asking the question already has a method to differentiate the most correct answer: accepting it.  There's no evidence that the asker knows any better than anyone else, and, seeing as they are the one asking the question, they probably know *less*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this would be a good idea. As random pointed out, the Asker is typically not the best person to determine who is providing the best answer, or even a good one. Granted, there are some instances where the Asker has that knowledge, but that isn't always the case. The other day I asked a question about the rewrite module in Apache, and waited to participate in the voting until after others had a chance, because I know that I am not very knowledgeable when it comes to .htaccess and mod_rewrite.

Know your own limits, and we will all be happy :)

Answer (score -1):

If we were to weight votes, I'd prefer the higher rep users have more weight. However, I believe that at least one high rep user requested this **not** occur.

Edit:

I should mention, that I am not in favor of weighting votes. I am merely stating that if we were to I believe that it should be the higher rep user's and not the asker.

Comment: That is a BAD idea. Mostly because it is yet another thing that discourages new users. You're now saying they are second class citizens because their mere votes (the only thing that is common across all experience levels) are now worth less. In the case of a user with 100 versus 100k, the new users vote would count for pretty much nothing.

Comment: @devinb, please note my revision, I am not in favor of weighting votes